# Replace semicolon between brackets in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I want to split this text into all the different characters in the story, but you can see there are notes and other data stored in brackets and parenthesis:

```
var string = "Batman [Bruce Wayne; also as Two-Face]; Joker; Ra's al Ghul; Mr. Freeze; Killer Moth; Poison Ivy; Mad Hatter; Spook; Scarecrow; Captain Stingaree; Cavalier; Cluemaster; Signalman; Batman [Jerry Randall]; Tweedle Dum; Tweedle Dee; Catwoman; Riddler; Lex Luthor; Superman; Two-Face; Commissioner Jim Gordon; Arkham Asylum";
```

In general you can split this string like so:

```
string.split(';')
```

And you'll get pretty close, but there are cases where there is a semicolon in between the brackets or parenthesis. So "Batman" in this case get broken into two characters.

QUESTION:
How can I remove the semicolons inside the brackets and parenthesis before splitting?

I tried a regex like this:

```
characters.replace('/(\[[^)]*);([^)]*\])/', '$1$2')
```

But doesn't seem to work.  Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/153542), I'd recommend writing a simple parser (they're not that hard really).

Comment: what do you want as output: ('Batman','Joker'...) or ('Batman','Bruce Wayne', 'also as Two-Face', 'Joker',...)

Comment: I want to have the extra "data' for further processing.  So it would be like (Batman [Bruce Wayne also as Two-Face], Joker, Ra's al Ghul)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this pattern should do it `/;(?=((?!\[).)*?\])/g` [demo](http://regex101.com/r/pD7wM2)

to match semicolons outside brackets `/;(?=(((?!\]).)*\[)|[^\[\]]*$)/g` [Demo](http://regex101.com/r/tL7aI2)

Comment: That only matches the first instance, which unless the OP gives more information, I doubt he wants.

Comment: @Esteban Felix when using the g modifier as in the demo it will match all semicolons between brackets

Comment: Good lord... been doing regex in js for too long, and had no idea it could do lookahead/behind :facepalm:

Answer (score 1):

Here you are:

```
/(\[.*?);(.*?\])/g
```

Example:

```
var string = "Batman [Bruce Wayne; also as Two-Face]; Joker; Ra's al Ghul; Mr. Freeze; Killer Moth; Poison Ivy; Mad Hatter; Spook; Scarecrow; Captain Stingaree; Cavalier; Cluemaster; Signalman; Batman [Jerry Randall]; Tweedle Dum; Tweedle Dee; Catwoman; Riddler; Lex Luthor; Superman; Two-Face; Commissioner Jim Gordon; Arkham Asylum";
string.replace(/(\[.*?);(.*?\])/g, '$1$2')

"Batman [Bruce Wayne also as Two-Face]; Joker; Ra's al Ghul; Mr. Freeze; Killer Moth; Poison Ivy; Mad Hatter; Spook; Scarecrow; Captain Stingaree; Cavalier; Cluemaster; Signalman; Batman [Jerry Randall]; Tweedle Dum; Tweedle Dee; Catwoman; Riddler; Lex Luthor; Superman; Two-Face; Commissioner Jim Gordon; Arkham Asylum"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove them or just protect the ones inside the brackets the same way...

Replace the semi colons you want to protect with an arbitrary string that won't occur naturally:

```
string.replace(/([\[\(][^\[\(\]\)]+);([^\[\(\]\)]+[\]\)])/g,'$1~~$2')
```

Replace the remaining semi-colons with a different arbitrary string that won't occur naturally (and clean up those spaces):

```
.replace(/; */g,"^^")
```

Switch the protected strings back to semi-colons:

```
.replace(/~~/g,";")
```

Split what you have left:

```
.split("^^");
```

...that should give you your desired result.

Comment: Yeah, I like this idea of changing it to an arbitrary string.  Be helpful for further processing.  Let me try this out...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to remove `;` inside square brackets before the split if you use this code:

```
result = string.split(/\s*;\s*(?![^[]*])/);
```

*(I added `\s*` to trim leading and trailing spaces)*